# How to initialize Firefox on wayland always by default?

Tags: firefox, wayland, desktop-icons

I want to initialize firefox on wayland always, also from the GUI, for now I can do it from the terminal using the following command:

```
MOZ_ENABLE_WAYLAND=1 firefox
```

That works, and also I know that I can put that as an alias, but what I would like to know is how to do the same by default i.e. When clicking at the icon of firefox at the GUI.

Comment: @Terrance, thanks for your answer, it makes plenty of sense, unfortunately I could´t make it work, maybe í'm skipping something.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Add the following to `~/.profile`:

```
# Firefox wayland:
if [ "$XDG_SESSION_TYPE" == "wayland" ]; then
    export MOZ_ENABLE_WAYLAND=1
fi
```

and reboot.

Comment: This worked after rebooting, maybe there is a way avoiding reboot, but is still ok, thanks!

Comment: Yes, this requires option requires reboot. Thanks, I've updated the answer!

Comment: If using Zsh, add to ~/.zprofile instead, and use `[[ .. ]]` (double brackets) instead of single ones (avoid `[ .. ]`)